# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ with netbeans 7.0.1, glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, mysql, jar, glassfish, netbeans-7

I have a class named `"Sta"`.

Every time I try to connect to the mysql Database I run into the exception:

> **2012/07/23 03:34:50SQLException: No suitable driver found for mysql:jdbc://127.0.0.1:3306/sta?user=root..** This exception  like
>   said occurs at:
>   **this.db_con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sta?user=root");**

What I've done so far is:

- Put the mysql driver jar into the library (via the project
  properties),
- put the driver jar manually into WEB-INF/lib (creaded the lib), and
- also put it into the library directory of the tomcat.

All with the same result 
(I'm using: **mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar** )

The project itself compiles and deploys normally except for the above exception.
Furthermore if I use the same connectionstring for a "normal" java - RMI application it works fine and without any hitches.

```
public class Sta_client extends HttpServlet 
{
    private Connection db_con=null;

    public Sta_client() throws ServletException
    {
        super();

        if (this.db_con==null)
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } 
            catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) 
            {
                System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }

            try 
            {
                this.db_con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/sta?user=root");
            } 
            catch(SQLException ex) 
            {
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
                Date date = new Date();
                System.err.println(dateFormat.format(date)+"SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you're having class path issues, but you shouldn't be creating your database connection in the constructor.  Do this in the doGet() method or better, setup a connection pool.

Comment: There is something strange, in your code it is `jdbc:mysql:...` but in the error message you provided it is `mysql:jdbc:...` which is the case?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans 7.0.1 has mysql connector.Remove your mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar and add jar that support in NetBeans IDE.